# Can't access nested JSON Api data: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Wondering if you could help. I am trying to access all the nested `first_names` from this API inside of `elements`:
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

Here's my controller code:

```
def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    object = JSON.parse(response)
    @testy = object["elements"]["first_name"]
  end
```

I am able to access all the data inside of `elements` just fine, but when I add `["first_name"]`, I get the error: *no implicit conversion of String into Integer*

Seems a bit weird? Surely it should just pull in whatever is inside of "first_name", whether it's an integer, string etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the least bit strange.

`object["elements"]` is an array and when you call the `[]` method on a array the argument is coerced into an integer as its used to access array elements by index:

```
irb(main):052:0> []["foo"]
(irb):52:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

> Surely it should just pull in whatever is inside of "first_name", whether it's an integer, string etc?

In other languages like JavaScript you would just get null instead because what you expect to be a single object is actually an array.

Do yourself a big favor and move the HTTP call and JSON processing out of the controller and into a separate component that you can test in isolation. It will make it a lot easier to spot simple issues like this.

Comment: Thanks - so the problem was these are an array of objects. So I have updated the code with no luck:
`elements = object["elements"]`
`@testy = elements.map{ |x| x[:first_name]  }`

As you can tell I'm very new to this, so how would pulling it out of the controller have helped me? I'm just going off of the errors that are shown in my local:host on refresh? Thanks

Comment: Create a separate class that you can call from the console or test in a unit test. Stop developing by browser. Its a dead end.

Comment: `@testy = elements.map{ |x| x[:first_name]  }` doesn't work since normal Ruby hashes don't have indifferent access. `{ "foo" => "bar" }[:foo] == nil`. You need to use `x["first_name"]`.